# Can you help me with some SWT List layout and rendering issues

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have been working on fixing a bug where adding around 2500 items to an SWT List was causing layouts to break, I believe this is a bug with the rendering in SWT because there was very little to go wrong, but when you scrolled down the list using a scrolled composite, at some point the next item in the composite would render over the list and the scroll would just stop (at around 2100) and items from the list just disappear. you can see this effect yourself if you comment out lines near 151 or my code.

However i have realised that if I add a height hint to the layout data of the List it will add it's own Scroll Bar and this will fix the rendering issue, but introduces a new issue, which is that I can't get the List to Greedily occupy the horizontal space, so that the scroll bar is on the right of the panel, Does anyone know of a way to get the List to stretch in this way?

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget;

public class FilterLayoutDialog extends Dialog {

    private ListDisplayer keyWordListDisplay;
    private ScrolledComposite scroll;
    private Composite parent;

    public FilterLayoutDialog(final Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(final Shell shell) {

    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.setSize(new Point(450, 550));
    shell.setText("FML"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public Control createDialogArea(final Composite comp) {

    scroll = new ScrolledComposite(comp, SWT.V_SCROLL);

    parent = new Composite(scroll, SWT.NONE);
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    scroll.setContent(parent);
    scroll.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scroll.setExpandVertical(true);

    scroll.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));

    final ToolBar keywordBar = new ToolBar(parent, SWT.RIGHT | SWT.FLAT);
    ToolItem addText = new ToolItem(keywordBar, SWT.RIGHT | SWT.FLAT);

    addText.setToolTipText("Add 3000");
    addText.setText("Add 3000");
    addText.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {

        keyWordListDisplay
            .setContent(IntStream.range(0, 3000).mapToObj(i -> i + "").collect(Collectors.toList()));
        parent.layout();
        setScrollSize();
        }
    });
    addText = new ToolItem(keywordBar, SWT.RIGHT | SWT.FLAT);

    addText.setToolTipText("Add 12");
    addText.setText("Add 12");
    addText.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {

        keyWordListDisplay
            .setContent(IntStream.range(0, 12).mapToObj(i -> i + "").collect(Collectors.toList()));
        parent.layout();
        setScrollSize();
        }
    });

    final ToolItem reset = new ToolItem(keywordBar, SWT.RIGHT | SWT.FLAT);

    reset.setToolTipText("Reset");
    reset.setText("Reset");
    reset.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        keyWordListDisplay.setEmpty();
        parent.layout();
        setScrollSize();
        }
    });

    final GridData barData = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
    keywordBar.setLayoutData(barData);

    Label sep = new Label(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SEPARATOR);

    sep.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).span(1, 1).create());

    final Composite keywordList = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    keywordList.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    keyWordListDisplay = new ListDisplayer(keywordList, "None Selected");

    sep = new Label(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SEPARATOR);
    sep.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).span(1, 1).create());

    setScrollSize();
    return scroll;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Display();

    final FilterLayoutDialog fml = new FilterLayoutDialog(new Shell());
    fml.open();
    }

    private void setScrollSize() {
    scroll.setMinSize(parent.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    }

    private class ListDisplayer {

    String emptyIndicator;
    Composite parent;
    Widget w;

    public ListDisplayer(final Composite parent, final String emptyIndicator) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.emptyIndicator = emptyIndicator;
        setEmpty();
    }

    void setContent(final Collection<String> content) {
        disposeWidget();

        Composite fill = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        fill.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);

        // Comment this out
        if (content.size() > 20) {
        GC gc = new GC(parent);
        gd.heightHint = gc.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * 20;
        }
        // End of comment

        fill.setLayoutData(gd);

        final org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List box = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(fill, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
        box.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
            box.setSelection(new int[] {});
        }
        });

        for (final String row : content) {
        box.add(row);
        }
        w = fill;
    }

    void setEmpty() {
        disposeWidget();
        final Label a = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.WRAP);
        a.setText(emptyIndicator);
        w = a;
    }

    void disposeWidget() {
        if (w != null) {
        w.dispose();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set layout data on the `keywordList` Composite, so it is being layed out as small as possible.

```java
keywordList.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));
```

works.

Note: It often helps to specify `SWT.BORDER` as the style for Composites when debugging the layout so you can see the space they are occupying (o set the background colour).

Comment: Thank you, any idea why the List goes wrong without the H_Scroll property?

Comment: If you are using Windows there are limitations on the size of the native controls that SWT uses - you may be hitting those.